# A circular reference was detected while serializing entities with one to many relationship

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

How to solve `one to many` relational  issue in asp.net?

I have `Topic` which contain many `playlists`.

My code:

```
public class Topic
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Image { get; set; }
    --->  public virtual List<Playlist> Playlist { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Playlist
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public int TopicId { get; set; }
    ---> public virtual Topic Topic { get; set; }
}
```

My controller function

```
[Route("data/binding/search")] 
public JsonResult Search()
{
    var search = Request["term"];
    var result=  from m in _context.Topics where m.Name.Contains(search) select m;
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

When I debug my code  I will see an infinite data because `Topics` will call `playlist` then `playlist` will call `Topics` , again the last called `Topic` will recall `playlist` and etc ... !

In general when I just use this relation to print my data in view I got no error and ASP.NET MVC 5 handle the problem .

The problem happens when I tried to print the data as `Json` I got

[image]

Is there any way to prevent an infinite data loop in JSON? I only need the first time of data without call of reference again and again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the error because your entity classes has circular property references.

To resolve the issue, you should do a projection in your LINQ query to get only the data needed (`Topic` entity data).

Here is how you project it to an anonymous object with `Id`, `Name` and `Image` properties.

```
public JsonResult Search(string term)
{
    var result = _context.Topics
                         .Where(a => a.Name.Contains(term))
                         .Select(x => new
                                          {
                                               Id = x.Id,
                                               Name = x.Name,
                                               Image = x.Image 
                                });
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

If you have a view model to represent the Topic entity data, you can use that in the projection part instead of the anonymous object

```
public class TopicVm
{
    public int Id { set;get;}
    public string Name { set;get;}
    public string Image { set;get;}
}
public JsonResult Search(string term)
{
    var result = _context.Topics
                         .Where(a => a.Name.Contains(term))
                         .Select(x => new TopicVm
                                          {
                                               Id = x.Id,
                                               Name = x.Name,
                                               Image = x.Image 
                                          });
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

If you want to include the Playlist property data as well, you can do that in your projection part.

```
public JsonResult Search(string term)
{
    var result = _context.Topics
                         .Where(a => a.Name.Contains(term))
                         .Select(x => new
                                          {
                                               Id = x.Id,
                                               Name = x.Name,
                                               Image = x.Image,
                                               Playlist = x.Playlist
                                                           .Select(p=>new
                                                            {
                                                              Id = p.Id,
                                                              Title = p.Title
                                                            })
                                });
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: thanks ,but it wont work , I can't select Playlist relation here

Comment: Yes you can. You can add that to the projection part.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have small experience here, what do you mean with projection part ?

Comment: haaaa ok , I just read your new update ,I will try now to see how it will works , thank

Comment: @Projection simple mean , Select